# CSS table td width - fixed, not flexible

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table and I want to set a fixed width of 30px on the td's. the problem is that when the text in the td is too long, the td is stretched out wider than 30px. `Overflow:hidden` doesn't work either on the td's, I need some way of hiding the overflowing text and keeping the td width 30px.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>first</td><td>second</td><td>third</td><td>forth</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>first</td><td>this is really long</td><td>third</td><td>forth</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 112, accepted):

It's not the prettiest CSS, but I got this to work:

```
table td {
    width: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Examples, with and without ellipses:

```css
body {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

table {
    border: 1px solid #555;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
}
table td {
    border: 1px solid #555;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
}

/* What you need: */
table td {
    width: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

table.with-ellipsis td {   
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>first</td><td>second</td><td>third</td><td>forth</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>first</td><td>this is really long</td><td>third</td><td>forth</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br />

<table class="with-ellipsis" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>first</td><td>second</td><td>third</td><td>forth</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>first</td><td>this is really long</td><td>third</td><td>forth</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Doesn't work in Chrome.  It creates a very odd stacked layout.

Comment: Right...edited. I'm not really sure about browser compatibility here.

Comment: Biggest problem is that it the display behavior changes from a table cell to a div style, with margin, border, padding, and orientation.

Comment: @DanielAntunesPinto: Yeah, I image the static width would be an issue with column spanning. This wasn't meant to be a solve-all solution; it's tailored to OP's needs ("i want to set a fixed width of 30px on the td").

Answer (score 58):

you also can try to use that:

```
table {
    table-layout:fixed;
}
table td {
    width: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp

Comment: For this to work, I think you still need to set a width on the table itself. So I think the answer from Daniel Rikowski is more accurate.

Comment: Marvelous. The other solution just removes the table layout, which doesn't work on Outlook for exemple. The table does need to have a width however.

Answer (score 38):

It is not only the **table cell** which is growing, the **table** itself can grow, too.
To avoid this you can assign a fixed width to the table which in return forces the cell width to be respected:

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 120px; /* Important */
}
td {
  width: 30px;
}
```

(Using `overflow: hidden` and/or `text-overflow: ellipsis` is optional but highly recommended for a better visual experience)

So if your situation allows you to assign a fixed width to your table, this solution might be a better alternative to the other given answers (which do work with or without a fixed width)

Comment: Yes, table width is the key!!

Answer (score 17):

The above suggestions trashed the layout of my table so I ended up using:

```
td {
  min-width: 30px;
  max-width: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

This is horrible to maintain but was easier than re-doing all the existing css for the site. Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: `overflow: hidden` is not even needed with at least Opera Blink.

Answer (score 1):

This workaround worked for me...

```
<td style="white-space: normal; width:300px;">
```

Comment: yep but it's deprecated since HTML4

Answer (score 1):

Put a `div` inside `td` and give following style `width:50px;overflow: hidden;` to the div
**[Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/bh6r3L7j/)**

```
<td>
  <div style="width:50px;overflow: hidden;"> 
    <span>A long string more than 50px wide</span>
  </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Chrome 37.
for non fixed `table`:

```
td {
    width: 30px;
    max-width: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

first two important! else - its flow away!

Answer (score -5):

Just divide the number of td to 100%. Example, you have 4 td's:

```
<html>
<table>
<tr>
<td style="width:25%">This is a text</td>
<td style="width:25%">This is some text, this is some text</td>
<td style="width:25%">This is another text, this is another text</td>
<td style="width:25%">This is the last text, this is the last text</td>
</tr>
</table>
</html>
```

We use 25% in each td to maximize the 100% space of the entire table

Comment: This has got nothing to do with the question