# Issues with table <td>expanding on long strings of texts

Tags: php, css, mysql, html-table

You may be thinking, "Hey kid, that's not an issue it's supposed to do that." And I am very well aware of that. However what I am trying to achieve is when the text in the box overflows the initial 50px I have set, I want the text to disappear, I have tried many things, including `overflow:hidden` and I just can't seem to figure it out. I know "Tables are for data not appearance", but in this case that is wrong... Also, I am attempting to avoid line breaks at all possibilities.

HTML:

```
<td>;
$picksql="SELECT * FROM ".$tbl_name."
WHERE PortNumber='".$i."'"; 
    $result=$conn->query($picksql);
    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['Entry1'].'<br>'.$row['Entry2'].'<br>'.$row['Entry3']; 
    $one=$row['Entry1'];
    $two=$row['Entry2'];
    $three=$row['Entry3'];
    }
</td>
```

css:

```
td{
width:50px;
height:70px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

disregarding the php, `$row['Entry1']` is what is echoed, and i cant seem to achieve my goal with it. Any Ideas?

Comment: Could always throw the content in a `div` or `span` (within the `td`) and apply your CSS rules to it (the container).

Comment: "in this case that is wrong"... No it's not. You're *using* them for appearance.

Comment: @ithcy fair enough but that is still less than helpful'

Comment: @JohnDoe I'm aware of that ;) But really that is the root of your problem. Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6658971/59461) will help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can reach this by adding `display: inline-block;`
I created fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QMCMA/ to demonstrate this