# Prevent size distortion of table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I created a pixel art maker that allows the user to choose a grid size of his or her liking. I added the following CSS to convert it to a two-column layout (along with divs in my HTML), in order to display the panel to the left of the grid:

```
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 35%;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

You can view my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/nataliecardot/pen/MQRxJZ) for reference.

However, the default 25 x 25 grid is taller than it is wide. I tried fiddling with `width: 35%;` but each outcome was distorted. How can I make it a perfect square?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because your table parent class has `width:35%` which means `table` will take `100%` of the parent width if table content exceeded, which will override the `td` width, but if table content is not exceeded the `td` width will work.

So you will need to use  `min-width: 20px` with `box-sizing: border-box;` instead of `width` in the `td`.

You can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765817/why-does-css-td-width-not-work)

```
td {
  min-width: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**[Updated Codepen](https://codepen.io/bhuwanb9/pen/OvgKbY)**

[image]

Comment: Using `box-sizing: border-box` should be more than sufficient :)

Comment: Your code worked (min-width was indeed needed), but it's still taller than it is wide. Any idea why that could be?

Comment: @NatalieCardot I think width and height are same...see the attached image above

Answer (score 1):

Add a `box-sizing: border-box;` to your td elements, it'll keep the borders in check with your width and height.

```
td {
  width: 20px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

When I checked your codePen, your tds were at 23x20, hence the difference in dimension of your grid.

Comment: I'm confused--don't see anything saying 23 in my files.

Comment: It's because without `box-sizing: border-box;`, borders, margin and padding are added to the `width` of the element. So when you ask for an element 20px wide with a 1px border, you end up with an element 22px wide instead (20px+1px border right+1px border left). With `box-sizing: border-box;`, they are taken into account and a 20 px element will be 20px wide(18+1+1px).

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. However, after looking into it a bit more it seems like margins are actually not taken into account when using `box-sizing: border-box`; just the padding and border.

Comment: True ! I rushed my answer, my bad. As you said, `box-sizing: border-box;` take only into account the content, the padding and the border.