# Table element td with relative width shrinks if there isn't enough text inside it

Tags: css, html-table

I have my table elements defined like this in my CSS:

```
table.index td{
width: 20%;
min-width: 20%;
}
```

But if there is not enough text to fill one whole line my table cells shrink! Why do this happen? I used `min-width`...

I don't like other anwsers on the forum where they use fixed width in `px` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658947/css-table-td-width-fixed-not-flexible). I would probably go with this solution (I mean fixed table elements) if I could add a customized and stylish horizontal scrollbar to my table. Maybee this would be even better.

My table looks like this:

```
<div class="index">
<table class="index">
<tr>
    <td>
        event 1
    </td>
    <td>
        event 2
    </td> 
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        event 6
    </td>
    <td>
        event 7
    </td> 
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: I expanded my question. Please take a look.

Comment: Ok I fixed it but the problem remains. It was a typo while writing my question.